# Imageflow and PNG-8

Tags: javascript, png, transparency, imageflow

I try to use a PNG-8 with the reflection effect. With a PNG-24 everything is working fine. But with PNG-8 I see black surfaces where the transparancy should be. Is it possible to use PNG-8 for Imageflow? What settings or parameters do I have to use?

Edit:

Seems that reflect3.php makes problems. Is there another solution for the reflection effect with PNG?

Comment: where are files `reflect3.php` and `reflect2.php` coming from?

Comment: I think they are provided by imageflow. In the beginning there is written `Easy Reflections by Richard Davey, Core PHP`. Further it stands `http://reflection.corephp.co.uk`. BTW: reflect2 is not for PNGs.

Comment: But imageflow calls either reflect2 or reflect3 depending on the parameters. So I think there is no other solution. Perhaps changing code in reflect3.php to make this work. But I don't know if this is generally possible.